# Intellij not importing updated jar

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project and I have created a new external jar called myjar. I subsequently updated my pom to myjar.17.1.snaphot from myjar.17.snaphot. In my external libraries, I do not see this jar - I still see myjar.17.snaphot. Therefore, Intellij cannot compile my code.

Whe I do a maven install at the command line, all works fine. Why doesn't intelliJ update my jar?

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.me</groupId>
            <artifactId>myjar</artifactId>
            <version>17.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the details. Is 'myjar' an external jar? Is it a maven-based project? How do you reference this jar in your pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ can not be aware of a change to an external dependency. When you change your version in an external dependency, there is no JAR installed into your local repo (`$HOME/.m2`). Once you do `mvn install` there is a file in this dir, IntelliJ notices it and adds it as a dependency.

A possible workaround is to add this external dependency to a parent pom as a module of your project.

**EDIT**

After installing you also need to update all references in your project poms to the new snapshot version, then right click on the `pom.xml` in Idea -> Maven -> Reimport.

Comment: How come I can see 17.1-SNAPSHOT in my .m2 folder?

Comment: It must be avaialable in a folder `.m2/repository/com.me/myjar/17.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Yes, that's where it is.. But Intellij is still referring to the 17 version.

Comment: Since 17.1 jar is in the correct .m2 folder, how do I get Intellij to forget about 17 and use 17.1?

Comment: You need to update all references in your project poms to the new snapshot version, then right click on the `pom.xml` in Idea -> Maven -> Reimport.